# Output pdf margin VS attributed margin in Latex

Tags: margins, geometry, double-sided

After a very long search on the net, I post these two questions:

The code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\setlength\evensidemargin{-0.23cm}
```

1)  The left margin of the generated pdf (and real sized paper), `d1` (`d1` and `d2` are illustrated in the figure below), is clearly different of the parameter `left` (`left=3.5cm` to get the desired margin `d1=4cm`). Why ? `left` seems to be equal to `d1 - some_parameter`, what is this `some_parameter` ? `d2=3cm`, it seems to be the same as `right`.

2)  I have a double side document, what is the right expression of `\setlength\evensidemargin` in order to dynamicaly inverse `d1` and `d2` for even pages? Tentatively, I made a manual assignment, I look for a dynamic expression.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need more space on the inner side for binding. This can be done in several ways.

Using `inner` and `outer`

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=4cm,outer=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-50]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `hmargin`

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin={4cm,3cm},]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-50]
\end{document}
```

Using `bindingoffset`

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm,bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-50]
\end{document}
```